# Prototyping optics for laser rangefinder

Tags: optics

I am a software engineer dabbling in optoelectronic systems. I can bumble my way through but I don't *really* know what I'm doing, and right now I'm figuring out how to prototype optical components. The application is an analog laser rangefinder. From the sensor datasheet, I need to find the correct lens(es) and positioning to focus a laser reflection dot onto a 12mm optical strip ([Datasheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/bf5d/0900766b81540441.pdf), [Manual](https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-10/DSA-187740.pdf)) at a size of 0.2mm. The sensor dimensions are based on a readily available part, the Hamamatsu S3932 analog PSD, but a different one could be used if needed. The distance and range are also somewhat negotiable. The circuitry [has been addressed in a seperate question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/609491/what-is-the-basic-circuit-to-wire-up-a-position-sensitive-detector-or-psd).

[image]

The size and intensity of the focused dot should be as consistent and bright as possible. I know binoculars use a combination of concave and convex lenses to achieve some kind of uniformly focused projection, but I have no idea whether this is the correct approach for this problem. I am completely at a loss at the moment when it comes to chosing dimensions, materials and properties, what the trade-offs are and where to source them. Finally, of course in a finished product the lenses I assume the lenses would be held in place by an enclosure, for which I assume I could use 3D printing. But to prototype it I assume I would be using a dark room and some kind of precision holders but I don't know what they are called.

Comment: What is your sensor? and link to a datasheet.

Comment: Can you modify your target? Adding a patch of retroreflective tape? Life is so much easier when the target is co-operative.

Comment: You might be better off cooking up your own precision holder since the precision holders typically refer to equipment that goes into peg tables for optical setups and every single piece of it costs a fortune. You just need locating pegs and an angle measurement ring.

Comment: Thanks, @DDuck! It's a Hamamatsu S3932, datasheet links added.

I would *somewhat* prefer not to modify the target but I wouldn't rule it out, either!

Comment: Thanks, @DKNguyen! Oh good to know I just assumed there would be a cheap 'n easy optical equivalent of an electronics breadboard you can order off optics shack.

Comment: @cmc If you find one let me know.

Comment: @DDuck The laser module could also conceivably be swapped for something more powerful if that helps.

Comment: There are optics breadboards, but optics / mechanics is expensive. Google: Edmund Optics, Thor Labs, Comar...

Comment: It looks, from your description, that you want not only the range but also some position data. These are, for all practical purposes, independent operations.  Are you trying to map an object's motion by tracking the movement of the spot centroid over time?

Comment: Thank you, @CarlWitthof! Yes, I will be taking measurements at random times, in effect graphing motion at up to something like 20khz. Do I assume correctly that the term range does not apply to my problem, referring to a more static measurement?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The outbound laser defines an axis and the only thing you can measure is the range along that axis (_z_). The range is translated by a lens into a positional change on the psd, which is sensed. Moving the target in _x_ & _y_ and any rotation doesn't change the position of the illuminated point on the psd

Answer (score 0):

With optics things need to be rigid and with the correct number of adjustments.

The S3932 is expensive - I'd start with a cheap webcam (sensor and lens) and looking at how the illuminated spot on the target moves with range - you'll need to keep relationship between the laser axis and camera fixed but it's not alignment critical as the camera is a 2d sensor.

You'll need to align the camera to see the spot at the nearest target position and at the maximum range. You can calibrate the system but moving the target and recording the change in position of the spot.

You should be able to estimate the centre of the spot by a centre of mass type fit.

This will give you some idea about the size of spot that you'll get and not have of worry about aligning the axis of the S3932 with the direction of motion of the imaged spot.

There is bandwidth tradeoff because the camera is updated every 20 ms or so vs the 100 kHz of the PSD.

Comment: Thank you! This is certainly a solution to a similar problem, however it does not solve mine. The sensor cost is not an issue, but I do specifically require an analog sensor output with sub-millisecond rise/low time. I am also fairly well covered with regards to the circuitry, I specifically need help building custom optics for this sensor, or a similar one. A few hundred euros for components and dev equipment is not an issue.

Comment: Use pencil and paper an the thin lens approximation for a ideal lens where you can place it and a reasonable diameter. 1/2 or 1 inch. Work the max range and one side of the PSD and the min range and the other end of PSD. This gives you the ideal lens. Shop for a lens. Rework the paperwork with that lens. Repeat- lens won't be right You need work out the motion of the spot to orient the sensor. You'll need a filter to reduce stray light. Ideally machine a part but 3d print kinda works but you're won't be 100% sure if you made what you wanted. You really want to move the sensor in X&y and theta.

Comment: Parts from the optomech people in the size you need will be awkward and expensive.

Comment: A camera can get you the motion in xy&theta and the lens for not much money. Choose the webcam so the diagonal of the sensor is bigger than the PSD. Then shop for a lens with similar focal length and replace webcam lens. Then you can determine the spot motion on the sensor. You'll also see how the spot shape distorts with range and that the focus and or abberations of the lens are suitable

Comment: Thank you, I will proceed with the given procedure!!!

I understand the advantages of the camera, and I would go down that route if I could, as I like COTS solutions as well. It is quite simply unusable for my application because of insufficiently low latency, and output as 2D array that requires processing power to digitally parse. <1ms response time on analog voltage is a hard requirement. What sort of lens is normally used? I lack search terms to find the right sort of optical part suitable for lasers. One plausible example lens would be enough to get me started.

Comment: It's more a ratiometric argument. The problem will be shopping.  There will be many lenses but not the focal length you want - they'll have coatings as be of different types. As your source is monochromatic you want to try for a singlet as they're cheaper.  You'll also need to think about the collimation of your laser module as this is part of your optical system too.

Comment: Much appreciated, @DDuck! Will take all into consideration. Sounds fiddly!